# Undefined variable Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this error on my view and i can't find where is the problem

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: errors
>
> Filename: views/register_user.php
>
> Line Number: 5

view:

```
<?php if($errors){ ?>
<div style="background:red,color:white;">
<?=$errors?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

and here controller

```
function register(){
    if($_POST){
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field'=>'username',
                'label'=>'Username',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|min_length[3]|is_unique[users.username]'
                ),
            array(
                'field'=>'password',
                'label'=>'Password',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]'
                ),
            array(
                'field'=>'password2',
                'label'=>'Password Confirmed',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|min_length[5]|matches[password]'
                ),
            array(
                'field'=>'user_type',
                'label'=>'User Type',
                'rules'=>'required'
                ),
            array(
                'field'=>'email',
                'label'=>'Email',
                'rules'=>'trim|required|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email'
                )
            );
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $data['errors']=validation_errors();
        } else {
        $data=array(
            'username'=>$_POST['username'],
            'password'=>$_POST['password'],
            'user_type'=>$_POST['user_type']
            );
        $this->load->model('user');
        $userid=$this->user->create_user($data);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userID',$userid);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_type',$_POST['user_type']);
        redirect(base_url().'posts');
    }
}
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('register_user');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

i'm starting using Codeigniter and i can't find the problem...

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question, but `$_POST` is only sent after a form is submitted via the `action='post'` method. If you don't have a form submitted, the page will error/warning message. You should probably wrap the `if($_POST)` inside a `isset($_POST)` first.

Comment: that is handled `if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that in some cases `$errors` variable isn't created. Use `if(isset($errors) && $errors))`

actually in the view all you need is `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`, no need to assign it to a variable

take a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html for more about how to show errors

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post `$data` to view. You should use like this:

```
$this->load->view('register_user', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<?php if(isset($errors)){ ?>
<div style="background:red,color:white;">
<?php echo $errors; ?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

**UPDATE:**
But you have a lot of other problems in your code. You need to clear it. For example: You didn't load the errors. And you let to create user without validation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php if(isset($errors) && $errors!=''){ ?>
<div style="background:red,color:white;">
<?=$errors?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this:

```
<?php if(isset($errors) && ('' != $errors) && (null != $errors)): ?>
<div style="background:red,color:white;">
<?php echo $errors; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```